# Remove * from a specific column value

Tags: python, string, dataframe

For this dataframe, what is the best way to get ride of the * of "Stad Brussel*". In the real dataframe, the * is also on the upside. Please refer to the pic. Thanks.

```
Dutch name             postcode Population
0   Anderlecht          1070    118241  
1   Oudergem            1160    33313   
2   Sint-Agatha-Berchem 1082    24701
3   Stad Brussel*       1000    176545
4   Etterbeek           1040    47414
```

Desired results:

```
   Dutch name              postcode Population
    0   Anderlecht          1070    118241  
    1   Oudergem            1160    33313   
    2   Sint-Agatha-Berchem 1082    24701
    3   Stad Brussel        1000    176545
    4   Etterbeek           1040    47414
```

[image]

Comment: Is your input file a text file only ? No specific format ?

Comment: It's a dataframe. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Dutch name'] = df['Dutch name'].replace({'\*':''}, regex = True)
```

This will remove all * characters in the 'Dutch name' column. If you need to remove the character from multiple columns use:

```
df.replace({'\*':''}, regex = True)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Indeed, without \ *, it will result the error: "nothing to repeat at position 0"

Answer (score 0):

If you manipulate only strings you can use regular expression matching. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

Something like :

```
import re

txt = 'Your file as a string here'

out = re.sub('\*', '', txt)
```

`out` now contain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

for dataframe, first define column(s) to be checked:

```
cols_to_check = ['4']
```

then,

```
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({'*':''}, regex=True)
```

Comment: This does not work in new versions of python and results in the error "Nothing to repeat at position 0". Use ```\*``` instead of just ```*```.

Comment: I was not aware of that. strange behaviour tho.. thanks for the info!